# Using SubQuery with Single Table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a single table that contains application forms with date & time fields showing access times for these forms.
The first select statement shows the all 3 fields of this table.

```
SELECT "DAY", R_TIME, FORM
FROM FORMHIST;
```

The second select shows occurances of all forms used on Mondays, but it needs to be broken out into form names versus being lumped together with one count.

```
SELECT DAYNAME ("DAY", 'CLDR 1.5:en_US'), COUNT(*) AS UniqueTimeAppeared
FROM formhist
where DAYNAME ("DAY", 'CLDR 1.5:en_US')='Monday'
GROUP BY DAY
```

And the last query shows a look at a single form for all date and times.

```
select *
from formhist
where form='MA41.gnt'
```

How would I best use a subquery or any suggested method to specificaly combine the last two queries to retrieve a list out of each form type with a count per days of the week.

```
Form ABC accessed Monday (100 times) 1/1/2013
Form ABC accessed Tuesday(250 times) 1/2/2013
Form XYZ accessed Friday (459 times) 2/2/2014
etc...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlht0.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmQ9C.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to include `FORM` in the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DAYNAME("DAY", 'CLDR 1.5:en_US'), FORM, COUNT(*) AS UniqueTimeAppeared
FROM formhist
-- where DAYNAME("DAY", 'CLDR 1.5:en_US')='Monday'
GROUP BY DAY, FORM;
```

Comment: Thank Gordon - this helps out greatly.  It shows the dayname - formname -  count of access for that day.  How do I add another return next to the dayname showing the date stamp (mm/dd/yy)?